# Get Elements value from Ajax response [Not duplicate]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to get values from an ajax response -- without any success, the closest I got was getting an array of undignified.

```
$.each(JSON.parse(response,function(i,value){console.log(value[1].buildings);}));
```

Here is a screenshot of my ajax response

[ajax response screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nkIu.png)

I need to store **name + success:false + column + message** to a variable as json

Thanks for your input!

Comment: What's the data in your response? I think it could be a problem with your JSON.parse() function because you use a callback here. Test it out here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: I do not see any correlation between your code and your screenshot. On your screenshot the response is already in JSON, so you donot need `JSON.parse`. Why do you need `$.each` ? why just do not concatinate everything together, like `result = response.name + response.success + response.column + response.message` ?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If you run the snippet below you can see that the fn variable is undefined. That's why your array is undefined. Remove the callback function from your snippet and it should work.

Solution:

```
$.each(JSON.parse(response));
```

```js
const json = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
const fn = JSON.parse(json, function(i, val) {
  console.log(i, val);
});

console.log('----');
console.log(fn);

const obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.count);
```

Answer (score -1):

Please check your datatype for hasCircuit. It should be integer

Comment: that's correct, I need to concatenate name + success:false + column + message